# PTIJ: Why are religious Jews so rude

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

Having walked around Brooklyn, I know that religious Jews never pay attention to others, and won't even reply to a friendly "hello" on the street. However, last year around this time it was even worse. I said "Hey, man" to someone and he started to boo! He even pulled out something that looked like a really fake gun and started waving it!

What did I do wrong that was so offenseful? How can I deal with religious Jews in a way that they will respond to??

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: You should try "Hey, guy" instead.

Comment: Maybe try "Moishe?" instead.  Then, unless he IS Moishe, you can follow up with "Oh, sorry, thought you were Moishe..do you know Moishe?"  And then he can respond with "Do I know Moishe!" and you two can have a grand old time the rest of the afternoon and become good friends...and maybe even meet Moishe!

Comment: No need to pick on the residents of New Square

Comment: @DoubleAA I would think it would be an honor to be from the kehilla in question

Comment: @SAH How is it ever an honor to be accused of being rude??

Comment: @DoubleAA if no one is accusing, I think it's fine

Answer (score 7):

I think it's rather obvious: he thought you were referring to that notorious   villain from the Megillah, King Achashveirosh. The Talmud (Megillah 12b) says that Achashveirosh was previously a stable boy, and that religious Jew thought he heard you say "**Hay** man", clearly referencing that evil monarch's former profession. The fake gun waving was a symbolic fulfillment of the Talmudic dictum "If someone comes to kill you, you kill him first" - Achashveirosh tried to kill the Jews (initially), so we brandish firearms to defend oursleves from the fiendish machinations of that sinister ex-'hayman'.

Comment: This is great. jjjjj