# PTIJ: What should be your 1st reaction to a foul-mouthed person who has laryngitis?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

On of my friends has a terrible tendency to speak *lashon hara*. I've warned him about this many times, and I try to cover my ears or walk away. But, he keeps doing this.

This morning, I said hello to him. He waved and signaled that he couldn't talk because he has laryngitis.

Usually, when someone is sick, my first response  is *refu'ah shleima* - Speedy recovery. But, since he usually speaks *lashon hara* almost immediately, I'm wondering if I should say the bracha *hatov vehamaitiv*, instead?

What's the halacha, here?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: Whatever you say, it better not be [“Hey, man”](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/80642/why-are-religious-jews-so-rude)

Comment: @DonielF True story - I've asked this question directly to 2 of my friends. Of course, I knew that they could take the joke. I don't recommend  saying this to someone whom you don't know too well.

Comment: Someone voted to close this as not Purimdik. I'm surprised nobody VTCed this as psak-seeking on that logic.

Comment: Whomever voted to close deserves a P.P. - Purim Patch ;-)